# How to get days between without time from date string - TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, datetime

I want to get the difference between days, but there is time and other information attached with this date format. 2021-04-05T19:12:33.000Z

How do we eliminate all the other time and just get the year, month, day fields to find the difference between days?

AKA
How do you convert
2021-04-05T19:12:33.000Z

to

just the year, month day and no seconds?
2021-04-05T00:00:00.000Z

or just get

2021-04-05? Or any other format to get the difference between 2 days and not considering the timestamps?

I'm thinking of extracting the year, month and day from the string and set it as fields.
Then pass it into

```
const year = ("2021-04-05T19:12:33.000Z").substring(0,4)
const month .. etc
```

new Date('05/04/2021') manually, but is there a better way to extract month, day, year from 2021-04-05T19:12:33.000Z ? Then find the days difference?

Thank you!

Comment: You can subtract the date objects from each other and divide the result by `24 * 3600 * 1000`. Now round down (or up) to get an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the different portions, just parse the date:

```js
const dt = new Date("2021-04-05T19:12:33.000Z")

console.log(dt.getFullYear())
console.log(dt.getMonth() + 1) // js is stupid and 0 indexes the month
console.log(dt.getDate())
```

To find the number of days between two dates, though,

```js
const dt1 = new Date("2021-04-05T19:12:33.000Z")
const dt2 = new Date("2021-04-11T19:12:33.000Z")

dt1.setHours(0);
dt1.setMinutes(0);
dt1.setSeconds(0);
dt1.setMilliseconds(0);
dt2.setHours(0);
dt2.setMinutes(0);
dt2.setSeconds(0);
dt2.setMilliseconds(0);

console.log((dt2 - dt1) / (24 /* hours */ * 60 /* minutes */ * 60 /* seconds */ * 1000 /* milliseconds */))
```

Comment: This is a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript

Comment: Great thanks Dave! I think it's different than the attached link since this is resetting items to 0 and using get dates instead of string manipulation

Comment: "2021-04-05T19:12:33.000Z" is parsed as UTC, *setHours* etc. set the local time. All time parts can be done in one call: `dt1.setHours(0,0,0,0)`. The result will not be an integer number of days where daylight saving is observed and the date range crosses a DST boundary.